# Async call waiting for variable to be settled in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My question is very simple. I have a global variable, `someVar`, that is initially set to `null`. Then I have a function like below:

```
someFunc: async function () {
   someVar = await someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean();
   var anotherVar = someVar;
   // call some function based on the state of anotherVar
}
```

I want to ensure that the `anotherVar` is not going to be set to `null` due to the fact that `someVar` was initially `null`. In other words, I want to make sure that `anotherVar` is set to a proper boolean that is the response type of `someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean()`.

Based on my understanding, using the `await` keyword means that any other part of the code within `someFunc` that uses `someVar` will wait (the keyword is `await` after all) for the line `someVar = await someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean();` to properly finish and for `someVar` to be actually set to a proper boolean. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of `await`.

Comment: Why use `anotherVar`, why not just keep using `someVar`?

Comment: Oups, my bad. Technically, it should say `var anotherVar = !someVar`. Notice the `!`. This is more accurate.

Comment: Why not just `someVar = !await ...`?

Comment: ... I think you're right you can probably do that. For some reason I was really fixated on having `anoterVar` AND `someVar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

The [`await` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) inside an `async` function will wait for the given Promise to fulfill, unless it isn't a Promise, in which case the value is directly returned. If the Promise got rejected, the `await` keyword throws the rejected value. If the Promise got resolved, it returns the resolved value. *If that's a Promise, it'll recursively await it.* Mind that (besides recursively awaiting Promises) it doesn't actually do/check anything with the value. If your `someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean` eventually resolves to `null`, you'll still end up with `null`.

On a side note: unless you already declared and initialized `someVar` before, it should be `undefined`, not `null`. Also make sure to declare `someVar` within your function. If it's a global, you *might* run in other issues, although unlikely. But good coding practices are good to follow anyway.

Comment: I this the underlying assumption is that `someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean` returns a boolean as the name implies. He's specifically asking if the variable's previous value can somehow leak through the `await`.

Comment: If the function returns `null`, then of course the variable will be set to that.

Comment: yeah exactly, as @Barmar stated, I'm wondering "if the variable's previous value can somehow leak through the `await`". If the promise is rejected, then of course it'd be set to `null`. @Kelvin Schoofs what do you think?

Comment: @Etfrerrr If the promise is rejected, `await rejectedPromise` actually throws an error before it gets to assign the variable. _Unless you add e.g. `.catch(() => null)`._ The only other "leaking" that could happen here is if `someVar` gets reassigned externally. After all, it seems like it's declared in another scope (or even globally if not using strict mode).

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs I see, thanks for the feedback. Sorry for the late response. But let's assume that the `someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean` is an asynchronous Ajax call (not a Promise, I believe) and that it successfully fetches the adequate data. In that case, there is no "leaking", correct? The line `var anotherVar = someVar;` will wait for `someVar = await someAsyncHelperThatReturnsABoolean();` to adequately set the `someVar`, so that `anotherVar` will be set to the proper boolean value of `someVar` (not it's initial null/undefined value).

Comment: @Etfrerrr `await` only awaits Promises (technically any object with a `.then` function but that's a very technical detail), so it won't wait for an asynchronous Ajax call unless you explicitly wrap it in a Promise you return, e.g. `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { someAsyncMethod((err, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)); })`